HP M110W Printer
I just got an HP M110W printer and configured it as per HP Smart and  connected it. It prints in Windows, but I use Ubuntu 22.04 (currently) 99.95% of the time. The printer shows in the Settings and, when I try to print a test page, it twitches but nothing prints. I installed hplip and the CUP libraries and can use lpstat, lpq,etc. but lp filename does not work either. I'm desperately hoping someone on this forum can help me print, otherwise I'm going to return the printer. I have run through all the procedures I found on the HP site but their Chat basically told me I'm on my own.

The solution was simple: changing to monochrome, which figures as the toner cartridge is black.
